# Why does "you rock" alert always pop up when I click?

Tags: javascript, html

I am a new javascript learner. I did this but don't understand why always "you rock" alert pops up when I click. Thanks in advance

```js
function favColors() {
  var example = document.getElementById('example');
    if(document.getElementById('favorite').value=example.options[0].text) {
      alert("you rock");
    }else {
      alert("have no color taste");
    }  
  document.getElementById('favorite').value=example.options[example.selectedIndex].text;
}
```

```html
<form>
    <select id="example" onChange="favColors()">
        <option>Black</option>
        <option>Red</option>
        <option>White</option>
        <option>Pink</option>
    </select>    
    <p>
        Your favorite sport is:
        <input type="text" id="favorite">
    </p>    
</form>
```

Comment: Please include the code directly in your post. Don't put your whole question in the title. Read the help about how to ask questions first.

Comment: Provide at least a link to the code, if not quoting it here.

Comment: @d.popov No, just a link is never appropriate.

Comment: Assignment v. comparison.

Comment: @Dave Newton. I see jsfiddle is tolerated, and for a reason. Codepen is the same.

Comment: @d.popov **Just** a link is *not* tolerated.

Comment: OK. I stop this now. I never said *just* a link is approperiate. I said *'at least a link to the code'*, it is a thing to improve, and there are a lot of questions like that. Please.

Comment: @d.popov My point was that "at least" a link to the code would still be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `IF` clause needs a `==` instead of a single `=`. It should look like this:

`if(document.getElementById('favorite').value==example.options[0].text) {`

instead of

`if(document.getElementById('favorite').value=example.options[0].text) {`.

Hope it helps.

Also, this:

`document.getElementById('favorite').value=example.options[example.selectedIndex].text;`

needs to be the first statement of right after defining `example`.

Update:

- The `example.options[example.selectedIndex].text` needs to be applied
  to `document.getElementById('favorite').value` before you can use it for  comparison.
- The `=` sign is for assignment and `==` is for comparison. So your `IF` statement needed updating accordingly. Read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators).

Answer (score 2):

You're using an assignment instead of a comparison operator inside of your if statement.

Assignment operator

```
//sets x to 5
x = 5
//sets y to an empty object
y = {}
//sets y to 5
y = x
```

Regular comparison operator

```
//evaluates to true
5 == 5
//evaluates to true
'5' == '5'
//evaluates to true
'5' == 5
//evaluates to false
'5' == 0
```

Strict comparison operator (the one you should be using)

```
//evaluates to true
5 === 5
//evaluates to true
'5' === '5'
//evaluates to false
'5' === 5
```